# Changing value of an Array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to change the value of an array without loop-

Example code:

```
<?php
    //current array
    $ids = array('1113_1', '1156_6', '1342_16', '1132_3', '1165_2');

    //result should be looks like this
    $ids = array('1113', '1156', '1342', '1132', '1165');
?>
```

is it possible to do it without any loop?

Comment: Your question can be improved. Can you explain why you want to avoid a loop, and whether your data is dynamic or static?

Comment: I've seen a couple comments about "this is still a loop" - you should be aware that you can't avoid a loop at some underlying level without processing it in a non-dynamic way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this using [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
<?php
function remove_end($n)
{
    list($front) = explode("_", $n);
    return $front;
}

$a = array('1113_1', '1156_6', '1342_16', '1132_3', '1165_2');
$a = array_map("remove_end", $a);
print_r($a);
?>
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/iGJ3cJW2

Comment: From the PHP manual: "Returns an array containing all the elements of arr1 after applying the callback function to each one." The loop is still occurring, but it is encapsulated in the array_map() call.

Comment: @George, neever said there was no loop in the back, but its definitely a shorter call

Comment: @Neal: OP said: "I want to change the value of an array without loop"

Comment: You'll find it in my posted answer, but of course it only works on non-dynamic data. A loop is required if the data is dynamic, so the original question may be flawed.

Comment: @Vury, your very welcome :-) remember to select an accepted answer when you can :-)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of the shown string/array function workarounds, you can also just use a PHP built-in to filter the arrays:

```
$ids = array('1113_1', '1156_6', '1342_16', '1132_3', '1165_2');
$ids = array_map("intval", $ids);
```

This converts each entry into an integer, which is sufficient in this case to get:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1113
    [1] => 1156
    [2] => 1342
    [3] => 1132
    [4] => 1165
)
```

Comment: It's a **built-in** PHP function. And please curb the `lol`. This isn't a forum here.

Answer (score 1):

Possible? Yes:

```
$ids[0] = substr($ids[0], 0, -2);
$ids[1] = substr($ids[1], 0, -2);
$ids[2] = substr($ids[2], 0, -3);
$ids[3] = substr($ids[3], 0, -2);
$ids[4] = substr($ids[4], 0, -2);
```

But why do you want to avoid using a loop in this case?

Comment: Then you will need a loop at some point. If your data is dynamic, you will need to act on each element, and a loop is the way to do that.

Comment: @Vural Acar: It's fairly rude to conduct a conversation with others online, and then delete your comments without warning.

Answer (score 1):

[`array_map()`](http://php.net/array_map), but internally it'd still be using a loop.

```
function $mycallback($a) {
   ... process $a
   return $fixed_value;
}

$fixed_array = array_map('mycallback', $bad_array);
```

Comment: If you don't know in advance how many items there'll be so you can write out each search/replace seperately, a loop is your only other option. Why do you want to avoid loops?

Comment: @Vury In what way is this [recursive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29)?

Comment: array_map has an internal recursion, array_map function will call the 'myCallback' until its done. Of course 'theoritically' there is noway to do it without loop or recursion. But i only wanted to know if is there a function to do my job without loop. Example $ids = array_unique($ids); which cleans the replacement values in an array and returns aa new array without loop. Thats what i mean.Well i am done with it anyway...